# Splitting a string only on multiple white spaces using python

Tags: python, string, split

My goal is to split the string below only on double white spaces. See example string below and an attempt using the regular split function.

My attempt

```
>>> _str='The lorry ran  into the mad man  before turning over'
>>> _str.split()
['The', 'lorry', 'ran', 'into', 'the', 'mad', 'man', 'before', 'turning', 'over']
```

Ideal result:

```
['the lorry ran', 'into the mad man', 'before turning over']
```

Any suggestions on how to arrive at the ideal result? thanks.

Comment: Is it only 2 spaces or any number of spaces greater than 1?

Comment: Hi @SukritKalra, 2 or more spaces. Thanks.

Comment: I added an answer which would split on any amount of spaces greater than 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`split` can use an argument which is used to split:

```
>>> _str='The lorry ran  into the mad man  before turning over'
>>> _str.split('  ')
['The lorry ran', 'into the mad man', 'before turning over']
```

From the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

> str.split([sep[, maxsplit]])
>
> ```
> Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter string.
> If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are
> done (thus, the list will have at most maxsplit+1 elements). 
>
> If sep is given, consecutive delimiters are not grouped together and are deemed
> to delimit empty strings (for example,
> '1,,2'.split(',') returns ['1', '', '2']). The sep argument may
> consist of multiple characters (for example, '1<>2<>3'.split('<>')
> returns ['1', '2', '3']).
> ```

Answer (score 2):

[`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) takes a seperator argument. Just pass `'  '` to it:

```
>>> _str='The lorry ran  into the mad man  before turning over'
>>> _str.split('  ')
['The lorry ran', 'into the mad man', 'before turning over']
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Give your [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) a double space as an argument.

```
>>> _str='The lorry ran  into the mad man  before turning over'
>>> _str.split("  ")
['The lorry ran', 'into the mad man', 'before turning over']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `re` module:

```
>>> import re
>>> example = 'The lorry ran  into the mad man  before turning over'
>>> re.split(r'\s{2}', example)
['The lorry ran', 'into the mad man', 'before turning over']
```

Answer (score 1):

Since, you need to split on 2 or more spaces, you can do.

```
>>> import re
>>> _str = 'The lorry ran    into the mad man    before turning over'
>>> re.split("\s{2,}", _str)
['The lorry ran', 'into the mad man', 'before turning over']
>>> _str = 'The lorry ran       into the mad man       before turning over'
>>> re.split("\s{2,}", _str)
['The lorry ran', 'into the mad man', 'before turning over']
```